# Mac Pro 1st Gen Graphics Card Question

Tags: mac-pro

I have just inherited a first-gen Mac Pro, however it comes with no power supply, no CPUs and a 7300GT graphics card.

My questions are:

1 - I know OS X needs an Apple graphics card to boot, is it possible to put the 7300GT in one of the slower PCI-Express lanes and put a PC graphics card in lane 1 (the x16 lane) and still have it boot? If not, what are my options? I intend to use the PC card only when booting to Windows.

2 - Power supply - Are there any PC PSUs that will work with this? What are my cheapest options?

3 - CPU - Are the bare minimum CPUs the Wolfdale Xeons? Will any desktop CPUs be compatable? Does the machine need two physical CPUs to boot?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to boot without a graphics card, but that will be an easy part to find.  The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Pro) is quite good about processor families so you have several options there. The apple power supplies are top notch, but you might find an equivalent.

Have you considered buying a scrap Mac Pro for it's power supply? I would be hesitant to spend money if I were not sure of the provenance of the stripped Mac Pro you have. (If the Mac worked, why strip the CPU, GPU and power supply? )

Good luck with your frankentosh!

Answer (score 0):

As far as number 1, yes, you can do this. Depending on the card, OS X may or may not boot properly with it in there. If it doesn't boot, you can always simply unplug the power to the card, and reboot - the 7300GT will work in another lane just fine. That's my current setup.

Not 100% sure about the answers to your other two questions I'm afraid. However, [Xlr8yourmac](http://www.xlr8yourmac.com/cpucards.html) has a list of CPU upgrades for Intel Macs, and a section for Mac Pros, which might shed some light on the CPU issue, at least.